# Why website is not auditable or readable for google?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pagespeed, google-crawlers, lighthouse

Have created a staging website on Herokuapp and production on AWS but whenever trying to audit or speed testing it's giving an attached error

1. http://findmy-web.herokuapp.com/ staging -> hosted on heroku
2. https://www.gocatchy.com/ live -> hosted on AWS

Technology used = node and react

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: When I try to open your live website I am getting a 502 Bad Gateway.

Comment: @GiorgosYiakoumettis please clear catch and check. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

folks issue is resolved.

As I checked server-side config there was context URL response with status code 400

res.status(400).send(fullMarkup);

have updated with 200 and its works!